# Am not getting my jquery menu sliding down in below code

Tags: jquery

Am not getting div_tech div sliding down when mouse comes over an element with id="non_tech" which is in another div which slides down on mouse over 'Events'

Related html code is

```
<div class="events">
   <img src="arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="img_arw" />
   <table class="tab_evnts">
      <tr>
         <td class="eve_mentd" id="tech">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="eve_men">Technical</span>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="eve_mentd" id="non_tech">
            <a href="#">
               <span class="eve_men">Non- Technical</span>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="eve_mentd" id="gamers">
            <a href="#">
               <span class="eve_men">Gamer&#39;s Inn</span>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <div class="tech_div">
   </div>
</div>

<table >
<tr>
<td class="menu"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></td>
<td class="menu"><a href="#" id="eves">Events</a></td>
<td class="menu"><a href="#" title="Tuneback">Tuneback</a></td>
<td class="menu"><a href="#" title="Registration">Registration</a>
</td><td class="menu"><a href="#"title="Helpdesk">Helpdesk</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Related jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eves').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.events').stop().slideDown("fast");
    }, function() {
        $('.events').stop().slideUp("fast");
    });
    $('#non_tech').hover(function() {

        $("tech_div").slideDown("slow");
    });
});​
```

Comment: I dont see the element with id `eves` in the posted `HTML`

Comment: Why do you have two functions in your mouseenter function and one in hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mouseenter` does not take two functions.. I think you are looking for `.hover()` or combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseout`

Looks like you are missing the **Class selector**

```
$(".tech_div").slideDown("slow");
   ^---------  Missing the class Selector
```

---

```
$('#eves').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.events').stop().slideDown("fast");
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $('.events').stop().slideUp("fast");
    }
});

$('#non_tech').hover(function() {
    $(".tech_div").slideDown("slow");
});​
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('#eves').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.events').stop().slideDown("fast");
    }
});

$('#non_tech').hover(function() {
    $(".tech_div").slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
    $(".tech_div").slideUp("slow");
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHRLv/1/)**

Comment: Your `tech_div` div is empty .. So what are you expecting to see

Comment: Check the updated code... I removed the `mouseout event` to make things more clear..

Comment: its k but i also want them to slide up when i move my mouse out of those div's

Comment: I have added the slide up for `tech_div` .. Its a bit more complicated for the events though.. check code

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in the selector

```
$('#eves').mouseenter(function() {
```

in your markup you defined a so named class, not an id.
try this

```
$('.eves').mouseenter(function() {
```

well... I'm not sure it's practicable to use tables for sliding menus, maybe you should try ul.

Comment: I don't see any element with class `.eves` either  .. You have `night vision goggles` maybe !!

Comment: I want .tech_div to slide down and #eves is sliding down

Comment: I want to slide down a menu from slided down div i want another div to slide down @Sushanth

Comment: <table >
    <tr>
    <td class="menu"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></td>
    <td class="menu"><a href="#" id="eves">Events</a></td>
    <td class="menu"><a href="#" title="Tuneback">Tuneback</a></td>
    <td class="menu"><a href="#"   title="Registration">Registration</a>
    </td><td class="menu"><a href="#"title="Helpdesk">Helpdesk</a> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>